# Battleship-java games

Tags: java

im learning to create a java game，still new to java. now i want to create a battleshipe game.
But now im stuck here. Now, when i randomly place the shipe as the computer board, sometime it will overlapping the previous ship, so it become not balance for then game. Second, after i get input from player, how do i put the input value into the board.
Here is the code i have:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Battleship
{
    public static void main (String args[]){
        String map [][][]=new String [10][10][2];
        int row =0,col=0;

        //initPlayerMap(map);
        //printMap(map,true);// true to printout the map
        placeShips(map); // place the shipe at computer map
        initMap(map,"~", true);
        initMap(map,"#",false);
        placeShips(map); // place the shipe at computer map
        printMap(map,true);
        System.out.println("Now enter your coordinate of the boom");
        row = getInput("Please enter row: ");
        col = getInput("Please enter col: ");
        printMap(map,false); // computer map
        hitShip(row,col);

    }

    private static void hitShip (int row, int col){
        if (map[startFrom++][colOrRow][1]== map[row][col][1]){
            System.out.println("abc");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("darn!");
        }
    }
    private static void initMap(String map[][][] , String initChar, boolean player){
        //the 0 in 3rd dimension is representing player map and 1 for computer
        int mapNo= (player?0:1);
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i ++)
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++)
                map [i][j][mapNo]= initChar;
    }

    private static void printMap(String map[][][], boolean player){
        int whichMap=0;
        if (!player)
            whichMap=1;

        System.out.println(" 0\t1\t2\t3\t4\t5\t6\t7\t8\t9 ");
        for (int i = 0 ; i < 10; i ++){
            System.out.print(i+" ");
            for (int j=0; j<10; j++){
                System.out.print(map [i][j][whichMap]+ "\t");
            }
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }// end of printMap method

    public static int getInput(String message){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print(message);
        return sc.nextInt();
    }

    private static void placeShips(String[][][] grid)
    {
        char[] shipType = { 'B' , 'C' , 'F' , 'M' };
        int[] shipSize = { 5 , 4 , 3 , 2 };
        int[] shipNums = { 1 , 2 , 4 , 4 };

        for (int x = 0 ; x < shipType.length ; x++)
            for (int y = 1 ; y <= shipNums[x] ; y++)
            {

                String shipName = shipType[x]+""+y;
                placeShip(grid,shipName,shipSize[x]);
            }
    }

    private static void placeShip(String[][][] map, String shipName, int size){
        int direction = (int)(Math.random()*2);// 0 or 1
        int colOrRow = (int)(Math.random()*map.length); // pick
        int startFrom =(int)(Math.random()*(map.length-size)); // which cell?


        // placing the ship
        for(int i=0; i < size; i++){
            // weather is vertical or horizontal
            // vertical
            if (direction == 0 ){
            map[startFrom++][colOrRow][1] = shipName;

            }
            else {
                map[colOrRow][startFrom++][1] = shipName;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.

Answer (score 4):

To start with, you haven't modeled this correctly (IMO)

I would utilize java.awt.Rectangle a lot more. I would start by making the board a Rectangle, then make each ship a Rectangle too. Because Rectangle (comes from Shape in fact) has the method contains(...) you should be able to quickly test whether your rectangles are overlapping.

As far as marking shots on the board, perhaps your Ships need to be defined as more than just rectangles - give them functionality for spots that have been hit. You can use java.awt.Point for hit / miss shots

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking two questions here, I'll answer them both.

1. To put a ship on the field and make sure they don't overlap, check if there is a ship in any of the squares you are trying to put your new ship into. Make a 2D array of booleans, in which you save on which square is a ship.
2. For the user input, what have you tried, and into what problems have you been running? Without anything to hold on to I cannot give you anything to work with. I'd suggest letting the user give two coordinates: the start and the end of the ship. Process that data.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be using a data structure to keep track of your "already filled" positions in your map. That way you can compare or "validate" what positions are not filled in your map.